# Limit amount in ps_cashondelivery Prestashop module

Tags: prestashop, payment-method

I need a restriction amount limitation to disable this payment method in Prestashop?

I tried adding code in hookPaymentOptions function:

```
/**
 * @param array{cookie: Cookie, cart: Cart, altern: int} $params
 *
 * @return array|PaymentOption[] Should always returns an array to avoid issue
 */
public function hookPaymentOptions(array $params)
{
    /* Code added */
    $limit = 500;
    if ($params['cart']->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH) > $limit) {
        return [];
    }
    /* Edn coded added */

    if (empty($params['cart']) || 10 > 1) {
        return [];
    }

    /** @var Cart $cart */
    $cart = $params['cart'];

    if ($cart->isVirtualCart()) {
        return [];
    }

    $cashOnDeliveryOption = new PaymentOption();
    $cashOnDeliveryOption->setModuleName($this->name);
    $cashOnDeliveryOption->setCallToActionText($this->trans('Pay by Cash on Delivery', [], 'Modules.Cashondelivery.Shop'));
    $cashOnDeliveryOption->setAction($this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'validation', [], true));
    $cashOnDeliveryOption->setAdditionalInformation($this->fetch('module:ps_cashondelivery/views/templates/hook/paymentOptions-additionalInformation.tpl'));

    return [$cashOnDeliveryOption];
}
```

But cash on delivery paymen method still display.

Any idea? Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It´s a problem with the params of the function.
Try this way for example

```
if ($params['cart']->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH) > $limit) {
        return [];
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Still doesnt work. I have edited my question and display all hookPaymentOptions function